# PermError SPF Permanent Error: Too many DNS lookups

Tags: email-validation, spf

I am trying to setup my SPF however when checking I get the error 
"PermError SPF Permanent Error: Too many DNS lookups"

I set my SPF record as "v=spf1 a mx include:secureserver.net ~all"

From my understandings the domain secureserver.net refers to 10 IPS - 
v=spf1 ip4:207.200.21.144/28 ip4:12.151.77.31 ip4:69.64.33.132 ip4:68.233.77.16 ip4:184.168.131.0/24 ip4:173.201.192.0/24 ip4:182.50.132.0/24 ip4:170.146.0.0/16 ip4:174.128.1.0/24 ip4:173.201.193.0/24

However if I put the A and MX at the start does this then mean it has 20 records which I know can only have a max of 10?

If so any idea how I fix this?

Comment: `include:secureserver.net` should only result in 4 additional lookups.  How many `A` and `MX` records do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The error too many DNS lookups usually indicates an infinite loop in the SPF configuration.  For example:

example.com SPF 'v=spf1 include:example.com ~all' will give the too many DNS lookups error.  So, there probably is a loop somewhere.

Simplify.  Instead of trying to include a record, how about simply this SPF record: 'v=spf1 ip4:207.200.21.144/28 ip4:12.151.77.31 ip4:69.64.33.132 ip4:68.233.77.16 ip4:184.168.131.0/24 ip4:173.201.192.0/24 ip4:182.50.132.0/24 ip4:170.146.0.0/16 ip4:174.128.1.0/24 ip4:173.201.193.0/24 ~all'